# Aligning values in a dataframe on same row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, append

My data is populating different rows and creating NaN values. Not sure as to why the rows aren't aligning.

```py
#Creating Dataframe
dfitems = pd.DataFrame(columns=['item_id','coverage_id','area_peril_id','vulnerability_id','group_id'])

#Populating columns
dfitems = dfitems.append({'item_id': 1}, ignore_index=True)
dfitems = dfitems.append({'coverage_id': 1}, ignore_index=True)
dfitems = dfitems.append({'area_peril_id': dropdown_property.value[-1]}, ignore_index=True)
dfitems = dfitems.append({'group_id': 1}, ignore_index=True)
dfitems = dfitems.append({'vulnerability_id': vulnerability.value[-1]}, ignore_index=True)

#Removing .0 with regex 
dfitems['vulnerability_id'] = dfitems['vulnerability_id'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
dfitems['area_peril_id'] = dfitems['area_peril_id'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
dfitems['coverage_id'] = dfitems['coverage_id'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
dfitems['item_id'] = dfitems['item_id'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
dfitems['group_id'] = dfitems['group_id'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)

#Drop Nan values
dfitems['item_id'] = dfitems['item_id'].astype(str).replace('nan', '', regex=True)
dfitems['coverage_id'] = dfitems['coverage_id'].astype(str).replace('nan', '', regex=True)
dfitems['area_peril_id'] = dfitems['area_peril_id'].astype(str).replace('nan', '', regex=True)
dfitems['vulnerability_id'] = dfitems['vulnerability_id'].astype(str).replace('nan', '', regex=True)
dfitems['group_id'] = dfitems['group_id'].astype(str).replace('nan', '', regex=True)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kim1X.jpg ['current output']

I expect the output of the data to all be on the same row.

Comment: [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) **Append(s) rows of other to the end of caller**. You want to append columns, so you should use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1`. Or just `assign`. But honestly, this is an overly complicated way to build a DataFrame. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with overly complicated. Why do you apply all your changes to each of the column and not the whole dataframe at once ?

The code below should do the same than yours but all the results will be on 1 row

```py
import pandas as pd
# Creating Dataframe & Populating columns 
data = {'item_id': [1], 'coverage_id': [4], 'area_peril_id': [dropdown_property.value[-1]],
        'group_id': [1], 'vulnerability_id': vulnerability.value[-1]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Removing .0 with regex 
df.astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True, inplace=True)

#Drop Nan values
df.astype(str).replace('nan', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```